# NiFi. There are too many outstanding HTTP requests with a total 100 outstanding requests

Tags: bigdata, apache-nifi

I'm having *There are too many outstanding HTTP requests with a total 100 outstanding requests* error each time I try to login to apache NiFi and sometimes when I'm working on the interface, memory and cpu are available on the cluster machines and NiFi flows work normally even when I can't login, is there a reason I keep getting this? And what can I try to prevent it?
[image]

Comment: Can you look in one of the logs (user or app) for this message at the same time you see this in the UI? logger.error("Cannot replicate request {} {} because there are {} outstanding HTTP Requests already. Request Counts Per URI = {}", method, uri.getPath(), numRequests, countsByUri);

Comment: Primarily interested to see the "Request Counts Per URI" because it should indicate which requests are not completing and filling up

Answer (score 0):

You can change `nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests` to a greater number. As stated [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#cluster_node_properties), the number of requests is limited to 100 by default, this would increase the possible number of requests.

It might not fix the problem that makes your cluster experience so many requests, but it could at least let you login to your cluster.